# skspritenode is getting stuck inside of any wall it hits

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode

My player moves by changing his velocity's dx to -200 or 200 based on which button is pressed, but sometimes when it hits a wall it gets stuck to the wall and can't move.  Is there any way to prevent this?

```
player.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i)*48 + 10, y*48 + 700)
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask  = playerCategory
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = wallCategory
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = firstPort | secPort
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
player.physicsBody?.friction = 0
player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
player.name = "Pl"
world.addChild(player)

let sprite: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "GTU.png")
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i)*48 + 10, y*48 + 700)
sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask =    wallCategory
sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCategory | firstPort | secPort | unopenedPortal
sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | unopenedPortal
sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0
sprite.name = "Block"
world.addChild(sprite)

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    _deltaTime = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
    if(isRightPressed == true){
        _playerSpeedX = 200.0
    }else if(isLeftPressed == true){
            _playerSpeedX = -200.0

    }else{
        _playerSpeedX = 0
    } 
    if(player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx == 0.0 && _playerSpeedX != 0){
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(_playerSpeedX), player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy + 170.0)
    }else{
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(_playerSpeedX), player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)
    }
}
```

Comment: need to see the code.  post the relevant parts, dont post everything

Comment: try enabling precise collision detection on the player's body, otherwise you may need to make him move more slowly

Comment: he's still getting stuck using precise collision detection, but after a few seconds  (holding onto the arrow going in the opposite direction) he breaks free.

Comment: even when i slowed him down, he still gets stuck in walls and stumbles on floor